# Pass a value to exported function using require

Tags: javascript, require

If I export a function like this:

```
const foo = "text";
const bar = function() {
    ...
}

module.exports = {
    foo,
    bar,
};
```

Is there any way to run the function `bar` when importing using require, e.g.

```
const { bar } = require('./myExports.js')('argForBar');
```

??

(currently when I do this I get the error `TypeError: require(...) is not a function`)

Comment: When you say "run the function", are you referring to `bar`?

Comment: yes - I have edited the question.

Comment: Do you really need this to be a one liner? Why not just call `bar('argForBar')` after defining the const?

Comment: Have you tried `require('./myExports.js').bar('argForBar')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require('./myExports')` returns an object, so you can't just invoke it like a function. If you export **just an object** with two fields, you will always get that 'require(...) is not a function' error.

You have alternatives like:

```
const bar = require('./myExports.js').bar('argForBar');
```

which doesn't need destructuring,or:

```
const {barF} = require('./myExports.js');
const bar = barF('argForBar');
```

Which destructures the `bar` function into the `barF` const, then call it.

Is there a problem with any of those?

At worst, you can do this trick, and export **a function which happens to have properties**, instead of a plain object:

```
const foo = "text";
const bar = function() {
    ...
}

const exported = function(param){
    return bar(param)
}

exported.foo = foo;
exported.bar = bar;

module.exports = exported;
```

This way, you make the module callable as the `bar` function, while it still is an object with the `foo` and `bar` properties. **But this is completely convoluted and I don't feel is what you're looking for**.

Comment: Why is this convoluted? That is the nearly the exact pattern the TypeScript transpiler follows if you export a class with static properties (especially in ES5 mode).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your import statement is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which is just syntactic sugar for declaring a variable(s) from an object property. You can either call `bar` after the assignment to get a new object, or you can do as Kevin Jantzer suggests and call the method in in the same line:

```
const bar = require('./myExports.js').bar('argForBar');

const { bar, foo } = require('./myExports.js');
const barInstance = bar('argForBar');
```